# Using paste() to display output in R

Tags: r

> Below is the code I have written, for some I am able to display output

```
data <- c(4,5,1,4,2,7,2,6,9,9,3)

#Mean
dt_mean = mean(data) 

#Median
dt_median = median(data)

#Mode
y <- table(data)
names(table(data))[table(data)==max(table(data))]

dt_mode <- names

#Output
cat("Mean: ", dt_mean)
cat("Median: ", dt_median)
paste(c("Mode: ", dt_mode))
```

I am getting output for Mean and Median in console correctly, but for Mode the below output is displayed:

```
{1] "Mode: "                ".Primitive(\"names\")"
```

As per the value of mode it have multiple values, what should I modify to get the output correctly?

Thanks!

Comment: `names` is a function.  You are assigning `dt_mode` to a function.  If you meant `dt_mode <- names(table(data))[table(data)==max(table(data))]`

Comment: you need to assign `names(table(data))[table(data)==max(table(data))]` to a variable before printing it. I guess you wanted to assing it to a variable `names`. `names` is a function and has no value. Try `dt_mode <- names(table(data))[table(data)==max(table(data))]`

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to assign your `names` from:

```
names(table(data))[table(data)==max(table(data))]
```

just do

```
dt_mode <- names(table(data))[table(data)==max(table(data))]
```

Explanation what happened in your case:

you printed `names` which is a function. When you write `names` in your console you get

> function (x)  .Primitive("names")

this return is, what got printed.

Full code:

```
data <- c(4,5,1,4,2,7,2,6,9,9,3)

#Mean
dt_mean = mean(data) 

#Median
dt_median = median(data)

#Mode

y <- table(data)
dt_mode <- names(table(data))[table(data)==max(table(data))]

#Output
cat("Mean: ", dt_mean)
cat("Median: ", dt_median)
paste(c("Mode: ", dt_mode))
```

Output:

> cat("Mean: ", dt_mean)
>
> Mean:  4.727273
>
> cat("Median: ", dt_median)
>
> Median:  4
>
> paste(c("Mode: ", dt_mode))
>
> [1] "Mode: " "2"      "4"      "9"

Answer (score 0):

Yes, because you are assigning the primitive function `name` to `dt_mode` and you are not assigning `names(table(data))[table(data)==max(table(data))]` to anything.

If you want to get the mode you can use this function from [here](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/r/r_mean_median_mode.htm) and then

```
getmode <- function(v) {
   uniqv <- unique(v)
   uniqv[which.max(tabulate(match(v, uniqv)))]
}

dt_mode <- getmode(data)

cat("Mode: ", dt_mode))
```